# How to guard against unsafe characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, razor

I have code in which I heard that there are unsafe characters in my code.

```
var listItem = $.trim(list[i]);                                    
$("<option value='" + listItem + "'>" + listItem + "</option>").appendTo(selectlist);
```

This is in a loop, but basically I am hearing that "listItem" has a quote in it or "other disallowed unsafe characters"

This is javascript/jquery in a .net / razor environment .   What are my options for "fixing" this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest making a...

`var $option = $('<option>')`

to create the element, and then you can...

```
$option.val(listItem);
$option.text(listItem);
```

to set the value and display text.  Doing it in this manner does not allow the html parser to try to parse the `listItem` value.  It treats it as a simple string.